# User.IsInRole("Admin") not working Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity-2

I am using `User.IsInRole("Admin")`in my Razor _layout.cshtml page to check the role of authenticated users and display the menu accordingly. The following is the code I am using:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <li class="@Html.RouteIf("index", "active")">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Dashboard", "home")" title="Dashboard"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i><span class="menu-item-parent">Analytics Dashboard</span></a>
                </li>
}
```

Now the problem is that the admin is logged into the systems successfully but no link is shown in the menu.

While Googling this problem I have made the following changes in my web.config

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
  </system.web>
```

and in

```
<remove name="RoleManager" />
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Supervisor"))
{
}
```

i use

> partialView
>   in 
>   **_Layout.cshtml**

```
<li>@Html.Partial("_SupervisorPartial")</li>
```

and it works fine now.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using System.Web.Security;
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var manager = new UserManager<IdentitySample.Models.ApplicationUser> (new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<IdentitySample.Models.ApplicationUser> (new IdentitySample.Models.ApplicationDbContext()));
    var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    if (user != null && manager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Supervisor"))
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm())
        { //your code
        }
    }
}
```